# c++ map class as key: compare function with recursive one

Tags: c++, dictionary

For using a map, it seems a comparison function is necessary. In the following example, the array c as a member of the class has four elements as c[4].

Question] When c[100], what is the best way to write the 'operator <' in a compact way?

```
class Configuration {
public:
    int c[4];
    bool operator<(const Configuration& other) const {
        if(c[0] == other.c[0]) {
            if(c[1] == other.c[1]) {
                if(c[2] == other.c[2]) {
                    return c[3] < other.c[3];
                }
                return c[2] < other.c[2];
            }
            return c[1] < other.c[1];
        }
        return c[0] < other.c[0];
    }
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a loop to iterate on each element while ```c[i] == other.c[i]``` and when it's different, return ```c[i] < other.c[i]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a standard function for this: `lexicographical_compare(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::begin(other.c), std::end(other.c))`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the many places where [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is *just better* than a C array.

```
class Configuration {
public:
    std::array<int, 100> c;
    bool operator<(const Configuration& other) const {
        return c < other.c
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Configuration {
public:
    int N = 100;
    int c[N];
    bool operator<(const Configuration& other) const {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i != (N - 1); ++i) {
            if (c[i] != other.c[i]) break;
        }
        return c[i] < other.c[i];
    }
};
```